# Js javascript code problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have a problem with my js code. So, i include in 'head' in my site, script

```
var Engine;

jQuery
(
    function($)
    {
        Engine = 
        {
            utils : 
            {   
                site : function(id)
                {
                    $('#content').html('<strong>Please wait..</strong>').load('engine.php',{'site':id},function()
                    {
                        os = {adres:'drugi'};
                        history.pushState(os,'s',ts);
                    }
                    );                    
                },

                topnav : function()
                {
                    $('div li').bind('click',function()
                    {
                        Engine.utils.site($(this).attr('rel'));
                        unbind('click',false);
                    }
                    );
                }
            }
        };
        Engine.utils.topnav();
    }
);
```

Now i want call included script in index.php

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    Engine.utils.site(1);
</script>
```

And here is a problem above code doesn't works.

But if i click on any 'li' element Engine.utils.site work's correctly.

Please help me i try fix it a few days.
Sory for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting the call in a ready function?

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        Engine.utils.site(1);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of closure. Your object `Engine` is not visible outside anonymous function